# using sequelize login authorization failed in node js

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to make some authorization api using sequelize, nodejs, jwt, mysql but it has some problem

```
router.post('/login', async(req, res, next) => {
    const {email, password} = req.body;

    findSalt(email)
        .then((doc) => createHash(password, doc.salt)) // password hash
        .then((hashedPassword) => findUser(email, hashedPassword)) 
        .then((user) => {
            if (user == null) {
                res.json({msg: "failed"}); 
                return;
            }
            let accessToken = jwt.sign({email, type: user.userType, verified: user.verified}, 
                process.env.JWT_SECRET_ACCESS, {expiresIn: '36000m'});
            /*
            let refreshToken = jwt.sign({email, type: user.userType, verified: user.verified}, // jwt 생성 후 토큰 반환
                process.env.JWT_SECRET_REFRESH, {expiresIn: '60m'});

            req.cache.set(email, refreshToken);
            req.expire(email, 60 * 10);
            */
            return accessToken
        })
        .then(token => { // save access_token in redis
            const parsedKey = 'access_' + email;
            console.log("parsedKey: ", parsedKey);
            return saveRedis(req, parsedKey, token, 60 * 5);
        }) 
        .then((token) => { // save token in cookie
            console.log("result token: ",token);
            res.cookie('accessToken', token, {secure: false, httpOnly: true,readOnly : true});
            res.json({msg: 'success'}); // 성공
        })
        .catch(err => {
            res.json({msg: "failed", err});
        });
});
```

this is login part

```
function findUser(email, password) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        User.findOne({
            where: {
                "email": email,
           "password": password
            }
        })
        .then(result => {
            resolve(result);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            reject(err);
        });

    })
}
```

this is find user function

```
function findSalt (email) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        User.findOne({where: {email}})
            .then(result => {
                resolve(result);
            })
            .catch(err => {
                resolve(err);
            });
    })
}
```

this is findSalt function

```
function createHash(password, salt) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        crypto.pbkdf2(password, salt, 100000, 64, 'sha512', (err, key) => {
            if (err) reject(err);
            const hashedKey = key.toString('base64');
            resolve(hashedKey);
        });
    });
}
```

this is create hash function part

I tried login through mysql, database password and console log are same but it failed login
is there any problem?

As you saw in my picture, database content and console log content are same

Answer (score 0):

I think your findSalt-function does not work as expected, since it is missing the field to search in:

```js
function findSalt (email) {
 ...
 User.findOne({where: {<name of field>: email}})
 ...
}
```

Comment: thanks for help but it doesnt work :)

Comment: i fixed problem thank you :) 
i forgot to send msg when i success login